# How to post a term with brackets with PHP to Sympy

Tags: php, python, sympy

I want to post a term like

```
5+(x+4)
```

from PHP via Python to Sympy in order to simplify the expression.

For that I'm using folowing code:
PHP:

```
$param="5+(x+4)";
$command="python $PathToPySkript $param"; //# '$param2' '$param3'";
$buffer='';
ob_start(); // prevent outputting till you are done
passthru($command);  
$buffer=ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

PY:

```
import sys
from sympy import *
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import *
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol
x = Symbol('x')
transformations=(standard_transformations + (implicit_multiplication_application,) + (function_exponentiation,)+(convert_xor,))      
print(latex(parse_expr(sys.argv[1], transformations=transformations)))
```

I'm able to post terms like

```
5+x+4
```

without any problem, retrieve the solution and display it on my website.

But for any term with brackets like ( or { or [, the processing throw errors or I would get no notice in PHP.

I tried also to double the brackets like (( or {{ or [[ but this will have no effekt.

Has anybody an idea how to get a solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution for myself!
The problem was that I have set the string like these:

PHP:

```
$param="5+(x+4)";
```

I changed this to:

```
$param="'5+(x+4)'";
```

Now it works as expected...